# C# Events as parameter in a method

Tags: c#, events

I want to use event itself in my method. Is it possible?
Can "PlayWithEvent" method use "EventSource.Test" event as parameter?

```
public class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler Test;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventSource src = new EventSource ();
        PlayWithEvent (src.Test);
    }

    static void PlayWithEvent (EventHandler e)
    {
        e (null, null);
    }
}
```

I want a syntax something like that:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventSource src = new EventSource ();
            PlayWithEvent (src.Test);
        }

        static void PlayWithEvent (event e)
        {
            e += something;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that. You need to pass the actual class.

```
public class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler Test;

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
       Test(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventSource src = new EventSource ();
        PlayWithEvent (src);
    }

    static void PlayWithEvent (EventSource e)
    {
       src.TriggerEvent();
    }
}
```

You can do it in a more generic way by introducing an interface:

```
public interface IEventPublisher<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    public void Publish(T args);
}


public class EventSource : IEventPublisher<EventArgs>
{
    public event EventHandler Test;

    public void Publish(EventArgs args)
    {
       Test(this, args);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventSource src = new EventSource ();
        PlayWithEvent (src);
    }

    static void PlayWithEvent (IEventPublisher<EventArgs> publisher)
    {
       publisher.Publish(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't compile—you can only access the `EventHandler` delegate for the event from within the same class as the event, and even then it would be `null` unless you actually add an event handler to call.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently working because you marked

```
public event EventHandler Test;
```

as an event.

Remove the event tag and try again.  It now works for me.  The reason for this are the restrictions that C# has for events...  But in your code, all you want is a delegate.  Declare your class as:

```
public class EventSource
{
    public EventHandler Test;
}
```

Note that I removed event:

```
public EventHandler Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the class that an event is defined on can raise the event. If you need other classes to be able to manipulate it, you'll have to use a regular delegate.

Note, however, that since `Test` resolves to the underlying delegate when used within the scope of `EventSource` (as opposed to the externally accessible event), `EventSource` *can* pass it as a parameter to an external method.